# Why is Species 8472 called Species 8472?

Tags: star-trek

This is my current understanding of the situation.
The Borg were the first to encounter Species 8472. Presumably, they called them Species 8472 because they have encountered 8471 species before them. Then, everybody else calls them Species 8472, because that's what the Borg called them initially.

1. Is what I've said so far correct?
2. What does Species 8472 call themselves?

Comment: You have to wonder why the Borg have only encountered 8471 species by this point.

Comment: They may have only designated species with numbers who they deem important enough TO number. Or maybe they discovered them a LONG time ago and their number is a reflection of that. The Star Trek Universe hasn't ever given an estimate of the number of species in their galaxy, so we can't tell if 8472 is a high number or not.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith There does seem to be an implicit "*intelligent*" qualifier to species, otherwise, the first moment one steps into an ocean at all like Earth's, one encounters thousands of species. :)

Comment: I think the writers thought Species 8472 sounded cool even though I think it's pretty ignorant of Janeway etc to call them that!

Comment: What I would like to know is why the Ferengi are Species 180.

Comment: I think Star Trek writers missed a big chance in "Q2." Q's son, instead of asking Janeway if she'd like to fight Species 8472, could've mentioned the species' actual name. (I refuse to believe that even a young Q wouldn't know this.) The crew would be confused, but then Q could say "you puny bipeds call them Species 8472," or something along those lines.

Comment: When you're in a position like Janeway and her crew, I'm sure they didn't want to take time to study and figure out a hostile species' real name. Yes they were exploring while traveling, but their main goal was to get home. So the easiest thing to do was just adopt the Borg name at least until they get home.

Comment: Is there any reason to assume the numeric designations the Borg use to distinguish species are directly related to the order in which they encounter them? Seems reasonable that they use some kind of taxonomical system or even just randomized identifiers instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Nothing in canon, but they are called the Undine in Star Trek Online.